# how to use custom.cnf in mysql server 8 docker-compose file?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mysql-8.0

trying to use custom configuration file in docker-compose mysql 8. The docker-compose.yml looks like

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    container_name: test-mysql8
    image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0
    volumes:
      - <host path to>/mycustom.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb
      - MYSQL_USER=testuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=testpassword
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always

  adminer:
    image: adminer:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Below is the custom config file, mycustom.cnf

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=32M
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_bin
transaction_isolation=READ-COMMITTED
```

Run the `docker-compose up -d` and verify the variables `docker exec -it test-mysql8 bash`

```
mysql -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8
Server version: 8.0.23 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show variables like '%max_allowed_packet';
+---------------------------+------------+
| Variable_name             | Value      |
+---------------------------+------------+
| max_allowed_packet        | 67108864   |
| mysqlx_max_allowed_packet | 67108864   |
| slave_max_allowed_packet  | 1073741824 |
+---------------------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Expecting the variable value as given in  `mycustom.cnf` as `max_allowed_packet=33554432` instead of `max_allowed_packet=67108864`

I know that command can be used in compose file as below, but I want to use custom file

```
......
command: --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_bin --max-allowed-packet=32M --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
......
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I tried to replace `image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0` with `image: mysql:8.0` and this worked.

Comment: this is not the answer to your original question tho. I'm faced with the same problem and changing the image does in fact fix it but I need to use a tag compatible with arm and x86.
I'd much rather you didn't accept your own answer and see if something more useful turns up for those of us with the same question.

Answer (score 10):

My way without config file. This is elegant when we only want to change a few parameters:

```
mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.29
    command: 
        --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        --max_connections=666
        --bind-address=0.0.0.0
        --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
    ports:
    - 3306:3306

    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
    - MYSQL_TCP_PORT=3399
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=appdb

    volumes:
    - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    - mysql_config:/etc/mysql
```

Check this with:

```
mysql -uroot -ppass -h127.0.0.1 -P3306 -e 'show global variables like "max_connections"';
```

[image]

An alternative to the configuration files. See details https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql official mysql docker image.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Saved me a lot of hassle.